# One mysql query between three table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables

```
1.Users
-User_id
2.Books
-Book_id
-Book_name
-User_id
3.Likes
-Other_User_id
-Book_id
```

I know only 'Users.user_id' and i want to know Book names and Like Counts of each book from likes table in the Books table.

Note: Users wrote books and other users like. So resulting JSON array will like.. i input mysql only user_id=10 and it printss....

```
{User id: 10 , Username: cemsitcan, Book Name: Sample, Book liked:120 times.}
{User id: 10 , Username: cemsitcan, Book Name: Sample1, Book liked:10 times.}
{User id: 10 , Username: cemsitcan, Book Name: Sample2, Book liked:123 times.}
```

Comment: And the issue is with...?

Comment: Do you ant wall books that the user likes, all books by the user that are liked or both? Seeing as this isn't a particularly difficult query, an attempt at it yourself would yield dividends especially as based on what you've asked the users table is irrelevant

Comment: please focus on json output then i want to see book name, author and total like counts from three table, i have only user_id at start, i give the user_id to the mysql and it tell me that his own books and like counts for each of them

Comment: Don't need three tables to do that User_id is in all three.

Comment: why downvote? do you know the query?

Comment: I didn't downvote and I'm just posting an aswer, as is someone else. I know why you got it though, basic tutorial on sql would teach this.

Comment: i need three for user name

Comment: Username, what username. No mention of username anywhere when I answered! You want the 'right' answer ask the right question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `User` table for this. If you use this query:

```
SELECT *, (
        SELECT COUNT(`Other_User_id`)
           FROM `Likes`
           WHERE `Books`.`Book_id`=`Likes`.`Book_id`
    ) AS `Likes_Count`
    FROM `books`
    WHERE `User_id`=10;
```

---

#### Fiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE Books
    (`Book_id` int, `Book_name` varchar(30), `User_id` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO Books
    (`Book_id`, `Book_name`, `User_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Hello World by 5', 5),
    (2, 'Hello World by 10', 10),
    (3, 'Microsoft by 7', 7),
    (4, 'Its a Small World by 10', 10),
    (5, 'StackOverflow is Great by 10', 10)
;

CREATE TABLE Users
    (`User_id` int, `User_name` varchar(15))
;
    
INSERT INTO Users
    (`User_id`, `User_name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Praveen'),
    (5, 'User'),
    (10, 'Praveen Kumar')
;

CREATE TABLE Likes
    (`User_id` int, `Book_id` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO Likes
    (`User_id`, `Book_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 5),
    (1, 1),
    (1, 10),
    (2, 10),
    (3, 5),
    (3, 10)
;
```

And the query:

```
SELECT *, (
        SELECT COUNT(`User_id`)
           FROM `Likes`
           WHERE `Books`.`Book_id`=`Likes`.`Book_id`
    ) AS `Likes_Count`
    FROM `books`
    WHERE `User_id`=10;
```

Output:

```
+---------+------------------------------+---------+-------------+
| BOOK_ID |                    BOOK_NAME | USER_ID | LIKES_COUNT |
+---------+------------------------------+---------+-------------+
|       2 |            Hello World by 10 |      10 |           0 |
|       4 |      Its a Small World by 10 |      10 |           0 |
|       5 | StackOverflow is Great by 10 |      10 |           2 |
+---------+------------------------------+---------+-------------+
```

---

If you would like even the author to be displayed with the result, you need:

```
SELECT COUNT(`User_id`)
           FROM `Likes`
           WHERE `Books`.`Book_id`=`Likes`.`Book_id`
    ) AS `Likes_Count`, (
        SELECT `User_name`
           FROM `Users`
           WHERE `Users`.`User_id`=`Books`.`User_id`
    ) AS `Author`
    FROM `Books`
    WHERE `User_id`=10;
```

The output is:

```
+---------+------------------------------+---------+-------------+---------------+
| BOOK_ID |                    BOOK_NAME | USER_ID | LIKES_COUNT |        AUTHOR |
+---------+------------------------------+---------+-------------+---------------+
|       2 |            Hello World by 10 |      10 |           0 | Praveen Kumar |
|       4 |      Its a Small World by 10 |      10 |           0 | Praveen Kumar |
|       5 | StackOverflow is Great by 10 |      10 |           2 | Praveen Kumar |
+---------+------------------------------+---------+-------------+---------------+
```

---

#### Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb1a4b/3

Comment: where is the first user_id ?

Comment: user_id's book names how can i list?
{User id: 10 , Book Name: Sample, Book liked:120 times.}
{User id: 10 , Book Name: Sample1, Book liked:10 times.}
{User id: 10 , Book Name: Sample2, Book liked:123 times.}

Comment: I don't understand. The first `user_id` is available in the `books` table right?

Comment: You know what, this outputs these fields: `book_id`, `Book_name`, `User_id`, and `Likes_count`. So you have the three items in this. Right? @user3557580

Comment: where user_id=?? , yes but i want to input user_id and it prints the JSON please look at it

Comment: If you are able to create an sqlfiddle, it would be awesome. :D

Comment: not working, what if there is no likes for the books? nothing shows?

Comment: Count will be `0` for that entry!

Comment: no, you have to make a book list, dont you ever used twitter? when a twit dont have likes it will not be listed ? hha, i want tweet detail, user id, username, like count. is that hard

Comment: I have used twitter, why?

Comment: when a twit dont have likes it will not be listed ? hha, i want tweet detail, user id, username, like count. is that hard, think like that

Comment: Wait buddy.. I am giving you a fiddle. You didn't include the username in the question at first! So wait!

Comment: @user3557580 Added including the username.

Comment: why You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Comment: works perfectly for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.user_id, b.book_name, count(l.book_id) from Books b
inner join likes l on l.book_id = b.book_id
Group by b.user_id, b.book_name
Where b.user_id = ?
```

Also your json output should just provide well named values, sticking format info in there like 'times' not to mention spaces in your names is a really bad idea. Let whatever is consuming the data choose how to present it.

Comment: so there must be 3 key:value on each row[] with this query. if a user has 3 books ; three json array with userid, bookname and books' like counts.

Comment: There'll be row for each of the user books from this query. Each row will be userid, book name and a count of likes, which is what you asked for. Obviously missing something here, but you aren't telling me what.